# Stopping the camera follow after player reaches a certain position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm a newbie working on a top-down 2D game and i want the camera to stop moving after it reaches a certain position so that the map doesn't get cut off. Its basically something like hunter assassin on the Play Store.

I haven't tried any kind of code but I do have the X and Y positions that are needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.